# Bidirectional @OneToOne not work when persisting child without parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, bidirectional

I have this situation :

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

  @OneToOne( optional = false, targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true )
  @JoinColumn( name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id" )
  private User user;

}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

   @OneToOne( optional = false, targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true )
   private Address address;
}
```

As you can see there isn't any cascade operation in both sides. But when I save a user :

```
userRepository.save( new User() );
```

It throws this exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.company.models.User.address; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.company.models.User.address
.............
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.company.models.User.address
```

I want to persist only the child, it should be possible since the `@JoinColumn` is in the parent, so I don't need to set it before saving.
Could someone clarify me this issue? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact your relationship between `User` and `Address` is being marked as `optional=false` which means it cannot be null.

So you either need to use `optional=true` and allow null-values or populate the `Address` relationship on your `User` before you persist it.

Comment: You're right, I'd just found that here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/one-to-one.html before your answer. But I even accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you get the null at id_user in the address table. Because during mapping the jpa doesnt set the value of user in address. You need to do it explecitely in setter of Address in the User entitiy as following.

```
public void setAddress(Address address) {
   address.setStudent(this);
   this.address = address;
}
```